# Maven error: Could not find or load main class .usr.share.maven.boot.plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar

Tags: maven, ubuntu

I have recently upgraded my Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 and started getting the following error when running any `mvn` commands (version 3.3.9): `Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.share.maven.boot.plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar`. My environment variables are declared as follows:

`$JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
$PATH: /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
$M2_HOME: /usr/share/maven
$M2: /usr/share/maven/bin`

When trying to find a solution, I've tried removing the M2 and M2_HOME variables as suggested on various threads, which resulted in getting a different error: `Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher`. I have also tried running `apt-get remove --purge maven` and installing it again as well as downloading the .tar.gz archive, but in both cases, nothing has changed.

When looking into the `/usr/share/maven/boot` folder, there is a chain of symlinks pointing from `plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar -> /usr/share/java/plexus-classworlds2-2.5.2.jar`. Am I missing some dependencies? Or are there any old configuration files that did not get removed by `--purge`?

*EDIT:* When I execute mvn as root, I get the Launcher error instead of plexus-classworlds-2.x. Also, I have completely removed and reinstalled all plexus libraries, yet with no change.

Comment: I assume you are using M2_HOME etc. and having installed an older Maven version (3.2.X +). Most important remove all things like M2_HOME, M2 etc. and only add the bin folder of the maven distribution to your path that's it (ok except the JAVA_HOME)..

Comment: Unfortunately, this still produces missing .usr.share.maven.boot.plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar error. Even if I manuall execute /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn -v, I get the same result.

Comment: You have somewhere in your environment such things. Have you removed M2_HOME and M2 etc. only keep /usr/shared/maven/bin in your path...

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 5):

Check if `/usr/share/maven/boot` has multiple jars with pattern `/usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-*.jar`.

Mine was something like:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec  23 14:21 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  4096 Nov  14  2015 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 52684 Dec  12  2015 plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    34 Dec  10  2015 plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar -> ../../java/plexus-classworlds2.jar
```

This messes up `/usr/share/maven/bin/mvn` bash script and executes a wrong java command.

I had to remove the jar and leave only the symbolic link.

Comment: Here's a one-liner fix for scripts, dockerfiles, etc. – it adds the suffix ".old" to any problematic files and leaves symlinks untouched:
 `find ${MAVEN_HOME}/boot/ -name plexus-classworlds-*.jar -type f -exec mv {} {}.old \;`